# Insert and Update data to database at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

```
function Writeform($name,$type,$num,$abroad,$datein,$cmnd,$address,$room_name){
    global $conn;
    $query= "INSERT INTO form 
    (Guest_name, Guest_type, Guest_num, Guest_abroad, datein, Guest_CMND, Guest_Address, room_name) VALUES 
    ('$name', '$type','$num','$abroad','$datein','$cmnd','$address','$room_name')";
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$query)){
        echo " added !";
        $sql="UPDATE room r INNER JOIN form f ON r.room_name=f.$room_name SET r.room_status='not avaliable'";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            echo " Record updated successfully ";
            }
            else{
                echo "Couldn't Update !!";
            }
    }
    else{
        echo "Couldn't Add!!";
    }
}
```

I'm trying to insert into database and update at the same time but I keep getting added and couldn't update!

Comment: Your second query `ON r.room_name=f.$room_name` shouldn't have the dollar sign. You're checking against the table field, not the `$room_name` variable.

Comment: how about checking for errors? `echo mysqli_error($conn);`

Comment: your database, structure ( naming conventions ) is all over the place, sorry just an observation.  For example `Guest_name,datein, Guest_CMND, Guest_Address, room_name` some upper some lower, some  mixed some with `_` some without.  This can cause a lot of unintened errors as the DB is case sensitive on Unix, but not windows. If I recall correctly.

Comment: What's this about, why are you joining on a variable named column? `ON r.room_name=f.$room_name` . `f` `dot` `variable` implies that the field in `f` is named after the room?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to join the tables in your `UPDATE` query.

```
$sql = "UPDATE room SET room_status = 'not available'
        WHERE room_name = '$room_name'";
```

But it would be better to use prepared statements.

```
$sql = "UPDATE room SET room_status = 'not available'
        WHERE room_name = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $room_name);
if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
    echo "Record updated successfully!";
} else {
    echo "Couldn't update!!";
}
```

Comment: did you see this, I think its odd `ON r.room_name=f.$room_name` but may imply some weird schema going on.  Still don't need the join, re-reading that "SQL".

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I don't think so. He just inserted the row into `form`, and it has a `room_name` column, there don't seem to be any dynamic column names.

Comment: And he inserted the value of `$room_name` into that column.

Comment: Here let me explain, say `$room_name = foo` then the query is `INNER JOIN form f ON r.room_name=f.foo`  as `ON r.room_name=f.$room_name`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I understand what you're saying. I doubt that's what he wants -- look at the `INSERT` query. It uses `$room_name` as the value of the `room_name` column.

Comment: Ok, as I mentioned and as you said the Join itself is unnecessary.  I agree with that.

Comment: You're assuming he knows what he's doing. I'm assuming he's like 99% of people who ask questions here and he's practically clueless, just trying random things until they work.

Comment: That is a fair point!